# Windowed Sum not displaying data correctly

Tags: t-sql, sum, subquery

I have a weird question for you. I have value coming from a sub query to which I am applying a Windowed Function in order to get a running total however, where the value is repeated (legitimately) the individual sums are getting rolled up into one. I will paste my redacted code and results below

```
SELECT
    ([SUB QUERY].[Field_A]/[SUB QUERY].[Field_B])*100 [Value],
    SUM([SUB QUERY].[Field_A]/[SUB QUERY].[Field_B])*100 OVER (ORDER BY [SUB QUERY].[Field_A] DESC) RunningTotal
FROM
    (
        [SUB QUERY]
    ) Dat
```

The results come out as shown below.

```
Value   RunningTotal
17.50501775 17.51
15.7074377  48.92
15.7074377  48.92
10.12725342 59.05
8.098755369 67.15
7.450983484 74.6
6.886517246 81.48
6.842160695 88.33
6.839469823 95.17
4.83496681  100
```

As you can see, the 2nd and 3rd lines both have a value of 15.7074377 but they are being added to the running total as a single value of 31.4148754. The running total for line 2 should say 33.21 and the 4th is correct.

Any idea whats happening here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the source data, meaning queries to create the table and insert the sample data

Comment: @Ronen Ariely Thanks for the reply

Comment: You are most welcome, but if you still did not get your answer, then I highly recommend to do what you were asked and not just wait for us. We have some info about the result of a query but no information about the source data and no source data to play with. Give us the tool to reproduce the issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess based on your info, but I think the problem here is that you actually need the sum of the sum. You could use a CTE to solve this, or just try this:

```
SELECT
([SUB QUERY].[Field_A]/[SUB QUERY].[Field_B])*100 [Value],
  SUM (SUM([SUB QUERY].[Field_A]/[SUB QUERY].[Field_B])*100 OVER (ORDER BY [SUB QUERY].[Field_A] DESC)) RunningTotal
FROM ([SUB QUERY]) AS Dat
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't show the data as it is all very sensitive and I have been instructed not to.

The good news though is I found the answer ([here](https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/)), as I was summing the same column I was using to ORDER BY in the windowed function, it will roll up all consecutive values if they are identical.

This will demonstrate the point though if you want to see it

```
DECLARE @Staging TABLE (Subtotal INT)

INSERT INTO
    @Staging (SubTotal)
VALUES
    (1),(2),(3),(3),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

SELECT
    Subtotal,
    SUM(SubTotal) OVER (ORDER BY SubTotal) RunningTotal
FROM    
    @Staging
```

Notice that the repeated 3 suffers the same issue I described above. By adding ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Field_A DESC) to the sub query I was able to sort by the new ID and it worked like a charm.